# ASP.Net Web Application Security dont work on IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, sql, security, iis-7, web-config

i am facing a wierd problem

i use visual studio 2010, SQL express 2008 on win server 2008

after running the wizard of security (created single user, set permissions like deny anonymous and allow the created user) and pressing F5 --> the site works just fine.

when i move the folder to IIS 7 and "convert to application" the login page appears but it wont accept the password i provided.

i was told that only Stackoverflow geniuses will answer this question.

i am using .Net 4, manged pipleine mode --> inegrated

**IIS settings:**

Anonymous Auth. --> Enabled

Forms Auth. --> Enabled

ASP.Net Impersonation, Basic Auth, Digest Auth, Windows Auth--> Disabled

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated     Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="statmaster"/>
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>    
        <clear/>    
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>

        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>  
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

the username exists in aspnet_Users table and the username "encrypted" in aspnet_Membership table

Comment: What authentication have you got set on the virtual directory? And what authentication have you specified in the web.config?

Comment: Look I'm not sure, but sinced it's 4 hours since you've asked this question and still not a single answer then I suggest you try to give us more info, as I could not point at anything (not claiming to be an expert!). Check IIS's and site's logs. The answer is obviously somewhere.

Comment: @Poni: please check the answer from mokokamello, it worked for me when i copied the application in the root folder, but not when i put it in a folder like "website1", please check the article in the link of mokokamello's answer and tell me your opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the article

[Always set the "applicationName" property when configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and other Providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx)

try creating a new website and put the application component in the root in case web.config application name = "/"

i hope this will solve it

```
  <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,      Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                enablePasswordReset="true"
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
  requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                passwordFormat="Hashed"
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
                passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" 
                applicationName="/" 
            />
        </providers>
  </membership>
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx